When using PostgreSQL cascading replication - How to promote standby to primary
I have 3 servers running PostgreSQL 9.6. I have cascading streaming replication working.
primary -> standby1 -> standby2
Any DB changes in primary reach standby2. So all good to this point.
However, if I failover and make standby1 to primary. standby2 stops getting the changes made on standby1. standby1 works perfectly as the the new writable primary, just no changes reach standby2.
What am I missing to allow standby2 to keep working as standby for standby1 when it's make primary?

Version 9.6, are you sure? This version is EOL since 2021. Advice: Upgrade to a recent version first, and then set up the replication and fail over. Many things have changed since 2016 (the release date), there is no point in waisting time on an unsupported version that works very different when it comes to replication.
